# Use Environment Variable or Parameter in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I try to add a proxy_pass in the nginx.conf like

```
location /example/ {
    proxy_pass   http://example.com;
}
```

But instead of hard coding http://example.com in the conf file I want to have this value in an environment variable.

How can I use environment variables in nginx.conf? Or is there a better way with nginx no have external configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want pure environment variables into nginx config, you will need implements some code in Lua Language:

https://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/environment-variables-in-nginx-config/

If you don't have a high load on this NGinx, I recommend implements this above solution.

In my specific case, to reduce CPU load, I prefer to use separated files with variables and a script in `rc.local` (or dockerfile) to change these files when launch the machine.

**conf.d/exemple.conf**

```
include backends/exemple.host;

location ~ ^/exemple {

    proxy_pass $exemple;
}
```

**backends/exemple.host**

```
set $exemple {BACKEND};
```

**rc.local**

```
sed -i "s@set \$exemple.*@set \$exemple $HOSTNAME\;@"  /etc/nginx/backends/exemple.host
```

To the last solution works, I need change the NGinx start order on O.S.

Comment: I will go with solution 2 because I use nginx on Windows and don't want to install lua. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use lua.

ex:

```
set_by_lua $curr_domain_name 'return os.getenv("DOMAIN")';
add_header Content-Security-Policy 'script-src  ${curr_domain_name}';
```

This worked for me.